# Icons are not visible in sidebar's list li class="nav-item"

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sidebar

I need to put icons before side menu's text. I tried many ways those are not working.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
<ul style="background-color:purple; padding-left: 20px;" class="navbar-nav mr-auto sidenav" id="navAccordion">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Property <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>        
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I tried below combinations

```
<li class="nav-item">
<a href="#">
  <li><a href="#">Envelope icon: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></a></li>
</a>
</li>

<li class="nav-item">
    <p><a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-home fa-fw"> </i>&nbsp; Home </a></p>
</li>

<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="fa fa-home fa-fw"> </i> Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
</li>
```

This is my output screen, where no icon available

[image]

Comment: Can you please add your full code in code snippet? Because we dont know that you have added font-awesome library or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are trying to use FontAwesome icons. Have you got the appropriate `fontawesome.css` referenced in your `<head>`?

Ie;

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">`

Comment: It's working now. Is there any other icons also there? w/o `font-awesome.min.css`

Comment: How do you mean sorry?

You mean icons that doesn't use font-awesome?
Check this: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-type.asp

Comment: Yes, bcz last week few icons was working w/o this lib.

Comment: by default, `<ul>`'s have icons, so you must have css that is removing the icon. Check the link I gave you that explains more.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this should help? Let me know.

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
<ul style="background-color:purple; padding-left: 20px;" class="navbar-nav mr-auto sidenav" id="navAccordion">

  <li class="nav-item">
    <div class="logo">
  <img style="width:25px; height:25px" src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20191120/original/pngtree-outline-home-icon-and-symbol-isolated-png-image_5045551.jpg">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
  </li>
  
  <li class="nav-item">
  <div class="logo">
    <img style="width:25px; height:25px" src="https://img.icons8.com/all/500/property.png">
                </div>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Property <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>        
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Edit: Just saw someone else answered your question. Glad you got the answer!

Comment: Thank for your answer.